# Securing root MYSQL user for LAMP stack

Tags: mysql, linux, lamp

**Context**

So I'm following the tutorial for securing MYSQL on a Linux machine from DigitalOcean (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-mysql-and-mariadb-databases-in-a-linux-vps) and I am at the section where we are renaming the root user so that it will be more difficult for people to gain unauthorized access to the databases.

After executing `rename user 'root'@'localhost' to 'newAdminUser'@'localhost';`, I see:

`+------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| User             | Host      | Password                                  |
+------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| newAdminUser     | localhost | *D95F7B9193493217A2F5AF587BB27C2F92EC2301 |
| root             | 127.0.0.1 | *D95F7B9193493217A2F5AF587BB27C2F92EC2301 |
| root             | ::1       | *D95F7B9193493217A2F5AF587BB27C2F92EC2301 |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost | *0BA36D18675A3EC9BBA779AAD0C189D798C886B1 |
+------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+`

**Question**

Should I be changing the name for the other root users? What effect would this have on my machine - does the machine expect to have these "root" users?

I appreciate your time and assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely remove the `'root'@'127.0.0.1'` user since it is equivalent to `'root'@'localhost'` (you can still connect to host `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` using root).

Changing the user name from root to something else provides a marginal security enhancement as a person would already need to have gained access to the system (either locally, or exploited a website and tries to connect from a script).

You can also remove the IPv6 localhost equivalent `::1` if you don't need to connect to MySQL locally over IPv6.

You should *not* delete the `debian-sys-maint` account as this is used by the system to perform [log related tasks](https://serverfault.com/a/9952/95039).

Answer (score 0):

As long as you ran `mysql_secure_installation` and removed root accounts *that are accessible from outside the local host* it shouldn't really matter from a security standpoint (unless you think someone will have SSH access to the machine, but shouldn't have access to the database).

But I would **still** change it, just for your own sanity - at some point you may be connecting to the database, and trying to use the `newAdminUser`, but MySQL sees you are connecting from `127.0.0.1` and so it says "nope, no user newAdminUser for that host, invalid password."